# Ruby Boolean Operators: word operators vs. sigil operators

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, are the word boolean operators (`and`, `or`, `not`) interchangeable with the sigil boolean operators (`&&`, `||`, `!`)?  Can I use either set of operators in my code, based on personal preference?

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby Boolean Operator Precedence

In Ruby, the C-style boolean operators (`!`, `&&`, `||`) are **not**
interchangeable with the "English word" boolean operators (`not`, `and`, `or`)
because they have different precedence relative to other Ruby operators.  The
latter are intended to be used for program flow control.  Example:

```
do_something_which_returns_true_on_success and
  do_something_else_only_when_the_first_thing_succeeds

do_something_which_returns_false_on_failure or
  do_something_else_if_the_first_thing_failed
```

#### Relative to Ternary Conditional Operator

```
1.9.3-p374 :023 > false and true ? "a" : "b"
=> false
1.9.3-p374 :024 > false && true ? "a" : "b"
=> "b"
1.9.3-p374 :097 > ! true ? 'a' : 'b'
=> "b"
1.9.3-p374 :098 > not true ? 'a' : 'b'
=> false
```

#### Relative to Assignment

```
1.9.3-p374 :061 > x = 'a' and 'b'; x
=> "a"
1.9.3-p374 :062 > y = 'a' && 'b'; y
=> "b"
1.9.3-p374 :110 > z = ! true; z
=> false
1.9.3-p374 :111 > z = not true; z
SyntaxError: (irb):111: syntax error, unexpected keyword_true, expecting '('
```

#### Relative to Comparison Operators

```
1.9.3-p374 :092 > def troo; true; end
1.9.3-p374 :093 > def falce; false; end
1.9.3-p374 :094 > troo == ! falce
=> true
1.9.3-p374 :095 > troo == not falce
SyntaxError: (irb):95: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '('
```

#### Relative to `defined?`

```
1.9.3-p374 :076 > undefined_variable
NameError: undefined local variable or method `undefined_variable' for main:Object
1.9.3-p374 :077 > defined? undefined_variable || 'a'
=> "expression"
1.9.3-p374 :078 > defined? undefined_variable or 'a'
=> "a"
1.9.3-p374 :079 > defined? undefined_variable && 'a'
=> "expression"
1.9.3-p374 :080 > defined? undefined_variable and 'a'
=> nil
1.9.3-p374 :083 > defined? 'a' && undefined_variable
=> "expression"
1.9.3-p374 :084 > defined? 'a' and undefined_variable
NameError: undefined local variable or method `undefined_variable' for main:Object
1.9.3-p374 :113 > defined? ! undefined_variable
=> nil
1.9.3-p374 :114 > defined? not undefined_variable
SyntaxError: (irb):114: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '('
```

#### Relative to Other Boolean Operators

The word operators `and` and `or` have the *same* precedence, and so are
evaluated left-to-right.  In contrast, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

```
1.9.3-p374 :150 > true || true && false
=> true
1.9.3-p374 :151 > true or true and false
=> false
1.9.3-p374 :153 > 1 || 2 && 3
=> 1
1.9.3-p374 :152 > 1 or 2 and 3
=> 3
```

The fourth case above (`1 or 2 and 3`) can be explained thus:

1. `1 or 2` is evaluated first.
2. This evaluates to the value `1`.
3. Then `1 and 3` is evaluated.
4. `1` is truthy, and so flow control is passed to the right side of the `and`.
5. The final value of the line is thus `3`.

The line of code is considered two different expressions.

Contrarywise, the third case above (`1 || 2 && 3`) is considered one single expression,
and short-circuits at the `1 ||`, returning the value `1` immediately.

```
1.9.3-p374 :163 > def meth1; puts "meth1 executed"; 1; end
1.9.3-p374 :164 > def meth2; puts "meth2 executed"; 2; end
1.9.3-p374 :165 > def meth3; puts "meth3 executed"; 3; end
1.9.3-p374 :166 > meth1 or meth2 and meth3
meth1 executed
meth3 executed
=> 3
1.9.3-p374 :167 > meth1 || meth2 && meth3
meth1 executed
=> 1
```